# What's the supremum of the set ${\{x:x<2}\}$?

Tags: real-numbers

By the definition of $\mathbb{R}$ as the Dedekind complete well ordered field, there should be such a supremum. What is it?

Comment: Can it be $\frac52$? Can it be $\frac32$?

Comment: No, since $2.01$ is smaller. Besides, Dedekind completeness means that it should be in this set.

Comment: Dedekind completeness *does not* mean that it should be in the set. It simply means that it should be in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Ok, so it's not $2.5$. Can it be $2.01$?

Comment: $\mathbb{R}$ is Dedekind-complete, $\{x : x < 2\}$ isn't.

Answer (score 3):

If we call the set $S$ the supremum should be a number $a$ such $x\le a$ for all $x\in S$, and if there exists some $a'$ with $x\le a'$ for all $x\in S$, then $a\le a'$.

Now, if you choose $a<2$ then you have $\frac{a+2}{2}\in S$ and $\frac{a+2}{2}>a$ which means $a$ cannot be the supremum.

Also, if you choose $a>2$ then $2<\frac{2+a}{2}<a$ meaning $x<\frac{2+a}{2}$ for all $x\in S$ but $\frac{2+a}{2}<a$ which means $a$ cannot be the supremum in this case either.

Therefore we must conclude $a=2$.

edit: as has been suggested, there is a clear upper bound of $3$ so our supremum must be at most $3$, meaning our supremum is not infinite either.

Comment: Might be worth adding in a short justification that the supremum isn't infinite.